# Tags here on Meta: "tagging" & "tags"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, meta

Here on Meta there exist both: [**tagging**](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tagging/info) and [**tags**](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags/info).

I propose a restructuring of the use of these tags.  I believe that **tags** should be used for all discussion of various tags, synonyms, etc, and **tagging** should be used for questions relating to *the action of tagging*.

This is not the way these are currently being used.  If making such a separation and retagging the meta questions is too disruptive it may be necessary to make these synonymous because they presently exist as redundant tags.  I would prefer to make the separation as I think it will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think the distinction *may* be useful, in principle, in practice, I doubt *the action of tagging* will be needed. So, a synonym is better.

Comment: I suppose it (tagging) could be from a support point of view.  E.g. "Retagging a question with no other edits shouldn't bump the question, should it?" (my own gripe just now)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it does bump the question

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree that retagging, in itself, isn't a real edit that should bump the question, count toward making it Community Wiki, etc...  Maybe not even count toward the editing badges. :-)

Comment: @rcollyer yes; that's not the point; I'm giving that as an example of a question (title) that would better be tagged with **tagging** rather than **tags** IMHO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, rcollyer: Now there are 3 tags: **tagging**, **tags** and **retagging**. I agree with rcollyer that in practice, one tag should be enough for all of these.